# Conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I'm trying to install APC (Alternative PHP Cache) on a CentOs dedicated server. I've everything done apart from configuring phpize. Running `:yum -y install php-devel` gives me the following error:

`file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386`
etc
etc for other languages

So, i think the MySQL version I have is too old & I more than likely need to upgrade mysql to version 5.1. Im reluctant to do this as a) its a live server (although only 3/4 domains) b) I've read I'll read to recompile PHP if I upgrade.

To add to this I have Plesk installed for managing domains & might need reinstalling/reconfiguring also.

Sorry for the long intro but it's my first post & best to give as much info as possible, so my question is basically,

Is there any way I can run `:yum -y install php-devel` to get phpize working to complete installation of APC for the version of MySQL I currently have installed? ie 5.0.77.

Comment: Please add centos mysql 5.0.77 phpize apc tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very good chance that APC is already in your yum repository which would allow you to install it without using phpize.

Try: `yum install php-pecl-apc`

(If it isn't in the default CentOS repository, try CentOSplus or EPEL if that is not an issue).

Edit: One more point of mention, it is unusual to get dependency problems if you are using a single repository - it sounds like you have multiple repositories enabled and might not be using the priorities plugin.

Comment: That worked a treat cyberx86, thanks ever so much. You saved me a lot of hardship, :))

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.x86_64 installed? Were you fooling around with a different repository?

Can you just yum remove mysql-libs? Then run from the APC directory:

phpize

configure --enable-apc

make && make install

and add (at minimum) extension="apc.so" to your /etc/php.ini

HTH